# How to make photoshop pattern base on real word object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I want to create an pattern out of the tablecloth in the picture below (I want to replicate the stripes combined with a pseudo linen texture).

[image]

I am a newbie to make this kind of thing (like mimic real world things). Can some give me some hints on how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that what you are looking for, is a way to create tiles with a pattern that will match on all sides. If you are not after tiles, but rather a whole image, the principle still stands.

You can either cut out a piece of the image, and with a little fiddling create a tile that will match itself on all sides (there are tutorials for this). This will probably get you into trouble with the light-and-shadow, so i suspect the best way would be to create it more or less from scratch.

You could start out with something like this; taken from the [Stripe generator:](http://www.stripegenerator.com/) (or, of course, make your own).

[image]

Then you can get a free linen-style image off the net (search for linen cloth), and fiddle with settings such as transparency, you could get an acceptable result. Or, you could create the linen texture yourself, directly on the stripey image (you could again use an [image generator](http://bg.siteorigin.com/), or you could follow a tutorial).